# how to write a javascript plugin(like jQuery) which can do string operations

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I would like to write a `javascript` plug in which can string manipulations something like `substring`, `replace`, `trim` and customized user functions.

Where from should i start to write (if there is no this kind of plug-in) ?

like:
`$("my string will be this").substr("will","would",{first});`

or

`$("my string will be this").replace("will","would",{fromLast,3});`

Comment: What about all the functions like that already supported by the Javascript String prototype? (Except "trim", but jQuery gives you that.)

Comment: I didn't know jQuery gives substring, replace ...? I want to add this plug-in to the strings. Like `$("my string will be this").substr("will","would",{first});` or `$("my string will be this").replace("will","would",{fromLast,3});` means start from last and replace only 3 words....

Comment: <nitpick>jQuery is not a "plugin," but a library built on top of javascript</nitpick>

Comment: jQuery doesn't give substring or replace — those functions are both built into JavaScript.

Comment: Except for trim,javascript has all built-in string manupilation functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://stilldesigning.com/dotstring/ ports prototype string functions to jQuery. Take a look at the code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JQuery - Javascript's own built-in string.replace() function uses Regex and is already far more powerful than the examples you suggested.

```
newstring = mystring.replace(/will/,'would');
```

(replacing specific instances of a word is harder, but achievable with regex)